# How to create two parallel running threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, twitter

I'm making a twitter analysis software with java and I want to create two threads that run in parallel: One is to stream the tweets using twitter streaming API and one is to analyze. I'm not sure of how to start .

Comment: There are tons of tutorials on the subject.  Did you try google?  Here's Java's concurrency reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: You also should look at the `ExecutorService` tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken right from a java tutorial. Let me know if you have specific quesitons:

```
public class SimpleThreads {

    // Display a message, preceded by
    // the name of the current thread
    static void threadMessage(String message) {
        String threadName =
            Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.format("%s: %s%n",
                          threadName,
                          message);
    }

    private static class MessageLoop
        implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            String importantInfo[] = {
                "Mares eat oats",
                "Does eat oats",
                "Little lambs eat ivy",
                "A kid will eat ivy too"
            };
            try {
                for (int i = 0;
                     i < importantInfo.length;
                     i++) {
                    // Pause for 4 seconds
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    // Print a message
                    threadMessage(importantInfo[i]);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                threadMessage("I wasn't done!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
        throws InterruptedException {

        // Delay, in milliseconds before
        // we interrupt MessageLoop
        // thread (default one hour).
        long patience = 1000 * 60 * 60;

        // If command line argument
        // present, gives patience
        // in seconds.
        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                patience = Long.parseLong(args[0]) * 1000;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Argument must be an integer.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        threadMessage("Starting MessageLoop thread");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
        t.start();

        threadMessage("Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish");
        // loop until MessageLoop
        // thread exits
        while (t.isAlive()) {
            threadMessage("Still waiting...");
            // Wait maximum of 1 second
            // for MessageLoop thread
            // to finish.
            t.join(1000);
            if (((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) > patience)
                  && t.isAlive()) {
                threadMessage("Tired of waiting!");
                t.interrupt();
                // Shouldn't be long now
                // -- wait indefinitely
                t.join();
            }
        }
        threadMessage("Finally!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the runnable method does not return anything and the analyzing thread that is running in parallel need to access the tweets retrieve from the streaming thread. My program so far have a list <String> method that take an arrays of string from the main function argument as a keyword to retrieve relevant tweets then would return a list of tweet in the array list. The other class will perform analysis on the list of tweets retrieve and generate results. I need to turn this into parallel process using thread.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need these as two threads?

Comment: I need to make it real-time so the program will have to run continuously.

Comment: That.doesn't mean you need two threads. One thread that handles both should be fine given what you've stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking at `java.lang.Thread` and `java.lang.Runnable`.
The most basic way to create a thread is to extend `Thread` or override `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, a thread is already a seperate process. So two threads are two seperate processes.

ie.

```
Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable()); // You have to implement the run() method
streamThread.start();

Thread analyzeThread = new Thread(new Runnable()); // You have to implement the run() method
analyzeThread.start();
```

That's all there is to it.